# Struggling with npm monorepo using Typesctipt

Tags: npm, monorepo

i have a monorepo app which contains two sub repo backend and frontend. Take a closer look at the screen below shown my currently sub directories backend and frontend
[image: app structure]

i'm currently in the root path, so i move in the frontend directory and then i hit `npm install` command in the frontend subdirectory i get node_modules and package-lock.json newly created

[image: frontend screen]

this behavior is not normal because i have linked up my subdirectories to my node_modules root and added these lines   in the root package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "gym-membersys",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Gym membersys ",
      "private": true,
      "workspaces": [
        "packages/*"
      ]
    }
```

and here is what i have in `tsconfig.json` root file

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true
      },
      "compileOnSave": true,
      "files": [],
      "include": [],
    
      "references": [
        { "path": "./packages/backend" },
        { "path": "./packages/frontend" }
      ]
    }
```

i'm using MacOs and visual studio code and npm version 8.3.1. Does anyone could help me i have been struggling for about 2 weeks thanks

Comment: Please add more details around *"...that's not what i want..."* and *"...doesnt works as expected..."* (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What's the expected behavior? NPM workspaces share the same node_modules and lock file. So to me that seems perfectly expected behavior. Why it isn't linking the packages on install that's a separate question and need debugging details (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yeah got you! actually my expectations is that when i run npm install in the sub module (ie Frontend) i don't want to end up with node_modules and package-lock.json created.

Comment: Why? Monorepo or not, those files will be created anyway. You can add them to .gitignore if you want to track them.

Comment: uhm it's seem like you're talking about a multi repo. I think that for a monorepo you can only have one package.json root and node_modules root files and each sub repo has their own package.json without necessary having node_modules

Comment: In which directory are they being created? The directory structure you showed in the first block looks perfectly fine to me. `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` will be there at the root. Are they getting created inside the frontend/backend directory?

Comment: exactly , they are getting created inside frontend/backend and that's why i made this post

Comment: Edit your question's description and title to make that clear. The way its currently written does not provide much information. You can remove the unnecessary information like tsconfig.json. Instead provide relevant information like how you're adding the dependency, how you're installing them, what's the working directory where you're running the commands, directory structure before and after installation, and which npm/node/os you're on. A repo link where we can reproduce the issue would be great too.

Comment: Sure! i edited the post to make it much more concise and clear let me know if its clear for you

Comment: Please add npm version too. You can get it by running `npm --version` on terminal. Workspaces syntax has been changing a lot between subsequent releases.

Answer (score 2):

That's how monorepos work.
Each package has its own `package.json` with its dependencies.
Dependencies in the root `package.json` are available globally (to each package.json) and shared. The ones specifically installed in the `package.json` of each sub-packages are available only there.

Answer (score 0):

> i'm currently in the root path, so i move in the frontend directory and then i hit npm install command in the frontend subdirectory i get node_modules and package-lock.json newly created

This is the root cause IG. You should install deps from the root itself. So say if you want to install `webpack` only for `frontend`, you should run this from root:

```bash
npm install webpack -w frontend
```

If you want a shared dependency (across all packages), do this instead:

```bash
npm install abbrev
```